# Music Lense not displaying music collection

Tags: unity, music, rhythmbox, lenses

I removed rhythmbox from 12.04 and now my music lense does not display any of my music.  Is there a way to get that back or do I now have a broken lense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Music lens` uses Music collection of *Banshee* or *RhythmBox.*

[Here](http://pastebin.com/YW6Luu4j) is snippet from Music Lense to make it clear.

So you must have either Banshee or Rhythmbox for Music lens to search for Music.

Comment: I should have seen that.  Thank you for responding.